# Eraser says filesystem not suported

Tags: hard-drive, wipe, eraser

I tried to use Eraser to delete specific files but it didn't work out. I get the error

> filesystem not supported

How do I solve my problem with Eraser?

EDIT: I'm trying to delete files on the same drive as windows 7 is installed.

Comment: I've edited your question to remove the [off-topic software recommendation](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) request.

Comment: What operating system are you running on? Are you trying to delete files on your system drive, an external drive, or elsewhere?